# Change The Classes Of List Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I want to change the class of each list(`#list`) item to the correspondent one at an `Array`. I have a list that is like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Strawberry</li>
    <li>Lemon</li>
</ul>
```

And I have this array:

```
["ban", "appl", "per", "straw", "lemn"]
```

What I want is that [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) `.addClass()` function to change each item with the `class` in the order as they are on the `Array`. To result into this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li class="ban">Banana</li>
    <li class="appl">Apple</li>
    <li class="per">Pear</li>
    <li class="straw">Strawberry</li>
    <li class="lemn">Lemon</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9zY/) for you:

```
var classes = ["ban", "appl", "per", "straw", "lemn"];

$('#list > li').addClass(function(index) {
  return classes[index];
});
```

You can see the documentation for this overload (the one that takes a `function(index, currentClass)` callback) [on the jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Comment: Given the OP has a specific class for each index in an array, I'm doubtful he cares about nested lists. Fixed anyway, though (thanks)!

Comment: Given the code presented, `.find()` would work just fine. You could always use `.children()` instead.

Comment: +1 this is also the most extensible of the solutions.  I'm thinking replace that array with a hash.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#list > li').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass( myArray[i] );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = ["ban", "appl", "per", "straw", "lemn"];
$("#list > li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(myArray[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, value){
        $('#list li').eq(i).addClass(value);
    }
);
```

Comment: This won't work because `.get()` returns a DOM Element instead of a jQuery object. Also, it's not a good idea to re-run the same selector in a loop.